# How to make the selectionLine to fit to the shape with cgSceneGraph?

Tags: javascript, html, api, canvas

I have a few questions about cgSceneGraph 1.4.2. I created a circle using `CGSGNodeCircle()`, and I would like the `selectionLine` to fit with the shape of the circle, is it possible?

Thanks, Allan.

```
circleA = new CGSGNodeCircle(180, 180, 90);
    circleA.position = new CGSGPosition (40,  60);

    circleA.selectionHandleSize = 10;
    circleA.selectionLineWidth = 10;
    circleA.lineWidth = 10;

    circleA.color = "lightgray";
    circleA.lineColor = "gray";
this.sceneGraph.addNode(circleA, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to answer so lately, but we are very busy working on the v2.

For your answer: 
For the circle with the v1.4.2, please use the one in provided in the "ecosystem" page of the website.

If you need to highlight a node, that's not the good way. The selectionLine is the bounding box of the node. It's used to manipulate it in a . So no, you can't get a selection line that have the same shape as your node.

If you want to highlight your node, there are several ways:

- have another node with the same shape and slightly bigger under your circle
- use an image to get a custom highlight effect with blur, ...
- ...

Please, let me know if you need new features.

Cheers.